# Selenium - accept untrusted certificates

Tags: selenium

I do the following code with selenium:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
```

I would need to know what it does to accept untrusted certificates (what does it changes in the options? **how to do it manually, by which I mean I open Firefox and I modify the property that does it**?)

The reason is this property solves problems, but I need to be able to do it to browser that are not being controlled by a selenium object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a method on the profile that takes a boolean!

`profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true)`

http://learn-automation.com/handle-untrusted-certificate-selenium/

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually what I mean is I know how to do it with selenium. I want to do what selenium does with this command, but manually.

Comment: Here is a link to their docs! Hope it helps! https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Untrusted-SSL-Certificates

Comment: thx!! checking it right away... will update as soon as is tested :)